# How to follow a link in man

Tags: manpage

When looking at man-pages in the terminal I often come across words with bracketed numbers after them (like `mkdir(2)`).
If I am not mistaken, these are links or references to other man-pages.

If so, how can I follow that link / find the referenced page?

If not, what does this mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to see all man pages about a command, one after the other, use the -a to man:

```
man -a mkdir
```

then use the `SPACE` bar, then `q` to quit the first page and then the `ENTER` key to see the next (2) page.

To find out more you can lookup the manpage of man using

```
man man
```

Comment: P.S. further for a funny output use `man women` ;)

Comment: `SPACE` and `ENTER` only get me to the bottom of page (1), not to the next one.

Comment: @schtreber sorry, I forgot to write: you need to quit `q` the first page first, then use `ENTER`.

Answer (score 3):

Not with `less(1)`, which is default pager in Ubuntu (and GNU in general).

There are several tools available, things that work in terminal and is not a full-blown GNU Emacs is called **info(1)**:

```
$ info apt
```

<kbd>TAB</kbd> to focus the next link, <kbd>M-TAB</kbd>¹ for the previous link, <kbd>Enter</kbd> to follow a link under cursor, <kbd>f</kbd> (for *follow*, I guess) to ask which link to go, completion available (usual <kbd>TAB</kbd> for that).

Please note, that when started `info(1)` defaults to a proper Info documentation (if such exists), rather than manpages.  If that is not what you want by some reason, you have to specify man section explicitly:

```
$ info 'mkdir(1)'     # that’s a man page
```

rather than:

```
$ info mkdir          # that’s a section in the full manual for Coreutils
```

__
¹ <kbd>ESC + TAB</kbd> if meta-tab (which might or might not be the same as <kbd>Alt + TAB</kbd>) does not work in your terminal.

Answer (score 0):

There are programs that can be installed or configured which can natively follow such links, such as [hacking vim](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/381182/272449), [pinfo](https://github.com/baszoetekouw/pinfo) or [w3mman](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/58464/272449).

There are many interesting ideas here:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18151/how-to-follow-links-in-linux-man-pages